# jquery datatable column header needs two cursors

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, datatables

I have a jquery datatable with drag and drop column enabled with sorting icon.

I need to apply cursor: pointer on hover sorting icon and cursor: move on hover other areas of column header

Though there is only one html tag `<th>` and sorting icon is also within that, I am not able to achieve this. Any suggestions/solutions to this.

Sample image to make question clear:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTables uses background image for sort icons. You need to change that to `:before` or `:after` so you can use different css styles for the icons and other ares of the header. With background you can not do this.

Example for normal icons:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background-image: url("../images/sort_desc.png");
}
```